# Javascript show hide dropdown doesn't work well

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

i have custom show hide dropdown menu, what i want is if i click the button, the list of options is showed, and when i click outside div or click the button again, list is hidden.

My problem is when i click the button to show the list then click outside the div to close it, the list will only show again if you click it twice (rather than the usual which is to click it once)

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {
  $('.option_down').hide();
  var state = "";
  $('.select_down').click(function (e) {
    // hide all span
    var $this = $('#options' + $(this).attr('target'));
    $(".option_down").not($this).hide();

    // here is what I want to do
    if (state === '#options' + $(this).attr('target')) {
      $this.hide();
      state = "";
    } else {
      $this.show();
      state = '#options' + $(this).attr('target');
    }

    e.preventDefault();
  });
  //ini aku pindah di document.ready
  $('.option_item_gender').on('click', function () {
    textGender = $('#gender' + $(this).attr('optionGender')).text();
    $("#select_gender").val(textGender);
    $('.option_down').hide();
    //trus aku tambahi koding dibawah biar tau kalau nutup semua
    state = "";
  });
  $('.option_item_city').on('click', function () {
    textCity = $('#city' + $(this).attr('optionCity')).text();
    $("#select_city").val(textCity);
    $('.option_down').hide();
    state = "";
  });
});

$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
  var container = new Array();
  container.push($('.option_down'));

  $.each(container, function (key, value) {
    if (!$(value).is(e.target) && $(value).has(e.target).length === 0) {
      $(value).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-8 medium-8 columns padding0" style="padding:0px;">
    <input type="text" id="select_gender" name="select_gender" class="search-box" placeholder="SELECT YOUR GENDER">
  </div>
  <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns padding0" style="float: left;"> <a href="#"><img src="webroot/images/select_down.png" target="1" class="select_down" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-8 medium-8 columns padding0" style="padding:0px;">
    <ul id="options1" class="option_down mCustomScrollbar _mCS_2" style="display:none;"> <a class="option_item_gender" optionGender="1"><li id="gender1">Male</li></a>
      <a class="option_item_gender" optionGender="2"><li id="gender2">Female</li></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns padding0" style="float: left;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-8 medium-8 columns padding0" style="padding:0px;">
    <input type="text" id="select_city" name="select_city" class="search-box" placeholder="CITY">
  </div>
  <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns padding0" style="float: left;"> <a href="#"><img src="webroot/images/select_down.png" target="5" class="select_down"/></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-8 medium-8 columns padding0" style="padding:0px;">
    <ul id="options5" class="option_down mCustomScrollbar _mCS_2" style="display:none;"> <a class="option_item_city" optionCity="1"><li id="city1">Malang</li></a>
      <a class="option_item_city" optionCity="2"><li id="city2">Denpasar</li></a>
      <a class="option_item_city" optionCity="3"><li id="city3">Surabaya</li></a>
      <a class="option_item_city" optionCity="4"><li id="city4">Jakarta</li></a>
      <a class="option_item_city" optionCity="5"><li id="city5" style="border:none;">Yogyakarta</li></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns padding0" style="float: left;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: "then click outside, then i want to show it again it need click twice" phrase is very confusing. what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: mouseup code is very strange.

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to achieve the same with less code, but to content with solving your problem, you just need to reset your `state` variable after you `$(value).hide();` and then put the whole `$(document).mouseup()` event inside the `$(document).ready()` event so the global variable `state` remains available to your `mouseup` event.

See the [working jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wzcvpu6f/).